# Radiobuttons and Checkboxes "checked" issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, zurb-foundation

I have Javascript code using `JQuery` to create quizzes containing free text, radio buttons (single choice) and check boxes (multiple choice) questions. The quizzes are made using a web interface, with `Zurb - Foundation` for the style, and are being serialized in JSON. While creating the radio buttons and the check boxes answers for an specific question, when an user checks either component (to mark it as the valid answer, for example), it's supposed to validate this, and come as "true" (represented by the number "1") in the JSON.

It's currently working for the text type question, as it is basically hard-coded. But it's not doing the trick for the other two.

Here's the main pieces of code (If more is needed I'll edit the question): Whole quiz

```
storeQuiz: function( event ) {
      var self = event.data;
      var store = [];

      $(self.element).find( '.question-content' ).each( function(){
        var question = $( this );
        var entry = { options: [] };

        if ( question.parent().attr( 'class' ).match( /template/ ) ) {
          return true;
        }

        entry['content'] = question.find( '.input' ).val();
        entry['type'] = question.parent().attr( 'class' ).match( /quiz-(\w+)/ )[1];

        question.find( '.option' ).each( function() {
          var option = $( this );
          var data = {};

          if ( entry.type === 'text' ) {

            data['valid'] = true;
          } else {
            data['valid'] = !!option.find( '.option-validation input' ).attr( 'checked' );
          }

          data['content'] = option.find( '.option-content textarea' ).val();

          entry.options.push( data );
        })

        store.push( entry );
      });

      self.storeUpdate( store );
    },
```

Radios:

```
buildRadios: function( data ) {
      var tmpl = this.radiosHandler( {data: this} );
      var self = this;

      tmpl.find( '.option' ).remove();
      tmpl.find( '.input' ).val( data.content );

      $.each( data.options, function() {
        var plus = tmpl.find( '.add' );
        var option = self.addAnswer.call( plus, {data: self} );
        option.find( '.option-validation input' ).attr( 'checked', this.valid );
        option.find( '.option-content textarea' ).val( this.content );
      });
    },
```

Check boxes:

```
   buildCheckboxes: function( data ) {
      var tmpl = this.checkboxesHandler( {data: this} );
      var self = this;

      tmpl.find( '.option' ).remove();
      tmpl.find( '.input' ).val( data.content );

      $.each( data.options, function() {
        var plus = tmpl.find( '.add' );
        var option = self.addAnswer.call( plus, {data: self} );
        option.find( '.option-validation input' ).attr( 'checked', this.valid );
        option.find( '.option-content textarea' ).val( this.content );
      });
    },
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser console? I'm wondering about the `tmpl.find( '.add' );` statement. I don't think `tmpl` is a jQuery object therefore I don't believe it will have the find method. Possibly `$(tmpl)`?...

Comment: @War10ck I'm not getting any errors, as far as I can see. I'm just checking the post file. Maybe some JS debugging could provide some info.

Comment: JS is probably where your error is occurring (if you get an error that is). When viewing the page in your browser, press ***F12*** to open your debugger console.

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem thanks to a friend with this fix:

```
data['valid'] = !!option.find( '.option-validation input' ).attr( 'checked' );
```

Changed to:

```
data['valid'] = option.find( '.option-validation input' ).is( ':checked' );
```

Comment: I would like to know how something that solved my problem actually deserves a downvote. But ok.

Comment: You're receiving downvotes because you credited your own answer as the accepted one, even though @maikay provided the same solution five days earlier.

Answer (score 6):

its smarter if you use

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked');
```

return value is boolean

Comment: Can you please point me to where should I change the code? It would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `attr()` when looking for checked values because it is actually a property so `.prop()` should be used.

```
if($('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked') === true)
{
    // checkbox is checked, uncheck it
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
}
else
{
    // checkbox is unchecked, check it
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

If you want to get fancy:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        alert('TRUE : checked');
    }
    else{
        alert('FALSE : unchecked');
    }
});
```

This is the reason that `<input type="checkbox" checked>` works without needing to do `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">`

When you check a checkbox with your mouse then the DOM object's property is set to Boolean TRUE and unchecking switches it to Boolean FALSE

Comment: Can you please point me to where should I change the code? It would be great.

Answer (score 1):

There is another easy way ..

```
if($('inputSelector')[0].checked == true) {
}
```

to set the checkbox use

```
$('inputSelector')[0].checked = true / false;
```